# Getting Object From JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get a specific object from my json response. My response looks like this

```
var list = [{
"count": 1,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "11",
        "description": "111",
    }
  ]
   }];
var products = list.results;
console.log(products)
```

The result in the console logs says that the object is undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `list[0].results`

Comment: list is an array, you should do list[0].results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` is not a JSON (since JSON is a string), it's an array, so you have to take the first element:

```
var products = list[0].results;
```

Answer (score 0):

List is an array use the array index to select the result

```
list[0].results;
```

```js
var list = [{
"count": 1,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "11",
        "description": "111",
    }
  ]
   }];
var products = list[0].results;
console.log(products)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON was located at 0th index in that array. so simply call your array with index instead calling without index.

```js
var list = [{
"count": 1,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "11",
        "description": "111",
    }
  ]
   }];
var products = list[0];
console.log(products.results)
```